# Why doesn't my order fill alert fire even when the order is filled?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

I'm facing an Alert issue in my script. My strategy contains both order fill alerts and script alert. `alert_Message` contains strings that will trigger orders to my algorithm software. It was working until Friday, but today it failed. The order fired and arrows show up in chart, but the alert message didn't fire.

Can anybody help?

BuySignal Triggered at 9.25 AM, arrows appear on the chart, but an alert message came without the message "BuySignal,zlsma".

```
Buy1 = close>zlsma and zlsma>ema and ema > ma
Sell1 =  ma>ema and ema>zlsma and zlsma > close
start = timestamp(2020,5,1,0)
end=timestamp(2024,12,31,0)

if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,1,when  =  Buy1, alert_message = "BuySignal,zlsma" )
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short,1,when = Sell1, alert_message = "SellSignal,zlsma" )
```

I have attached a chart screenshot and Alert screenshot:

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: i have revised the post. please have a look . i m not able to images.

Comment: my issue got solved. it was a simple code mistake. sorry for the trouble.